# Introductory paragraph only in list of blog posts

Tags: list

My blog is displaying the full post of my latest blog post, instead of an introductory paragraph only.

How do I make it show an introductory paragraph only, so readers need to click into the full post?

Here's the blog: http://richardclunan.com/blog/

(I haven't posted on it in a while and I can't remember how to do this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [more tag](http://en.support.wordpress.com/splitting-content/more-tag/). The documentation is from WordPress.com, but it works the same on self-hosted installs.